JsonValue.GetValue<string>?
How can I get the value "AUD" in Delphi?
{"AUD":{"code":"AUD","value":1.5035301824}

with :
Branch := JsonValue.GetValue<string>('meta.data{0}.AUD.code');

?
complete JSON statement:
{"meta":{"last_updated_at":"2024-06-01T23:59:59Z"},"data":{"AUD":{"code":"AUD","value":1.5035301824},"CAD":{"code":"CAD","value":1.3630401556},"EUR":{"code":"EUR","value":0.9217301503},"IDR":{"code":"IDR","value":16238.265355613},"USD":{"code":"USD","value":1}}}

label1 = AUD
label2 = 1.5035301824

Why are you using data{0} instead of just data in your JSON path expression? {0} is not valid path syntax.

If you look closely at the JSON you will notice that the branch you are looking for has nothing to do with the meta property - see the formatted json:
{
  "meta":{
    "last_updated_at":"2024-06-01T23:59:59Z"
  },
  "data":{
    "AUD":{
      "code":"AUD",
      "value":1.5035301824
    },
    "CAD":{
      "code":"CAD",
      "value":1.3630401556
    },
    "EUR":{
      "code":"EUR",
      "value":0.9217301503
    },
    "IDR":{
      "code":"IDR",
      "value":16238.265355613
    },
    "USD":{
      "code":"USD",
      "value":1
    }
  }
}

This makes it clear the path you are looking for is 'data.AUD.code'.

Branch := JsonValue.GetValue('data.AUD.code'); ?
